# Файлы удаляются при merge GIT

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-merge

Долгое время пользовался GIT'ом, но проблемы набросились только сегодня

Структура

```
branch: master
... еще 7 папок вне 
└── blueprints
    └── create
        ├── questions.py
        ├── sa
        ├── section_items.py
        ├── survey.py
        ├── tag.py
        └── variations.py
```

Я создаю новую ветку и пытаюсь работать в "идеальной" обстановке

```
git checkout -b audition
```

После я удаляю все папки и файлы кроме папки *blueprints*

```
git rm -r --cached .
git rm -rm .
```

В этой папке я создаю папку (модуль) *audition* и все остальное. Делаю *commit*.
Итог:

```
branch: audition
только эта папка
└── blueprints
    └── audirion
        ├── home.py
        ├── section_items_audirion.py
        ├── storm.py
        ├── postm.py
        └── airblob.py
```

Теперь я хочу соеденить ветку *audition* с *master*

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff -m "Merge audition module" audition
```

В итоге я получаю на ветке *master*, структу ветки *audition* и ничего более!
Все файлы которые были вне blueprints исчезли, папка create тоже...

Что я не так делаю?

Comment: Вы удаляете файлы, и потому-то они и удаляются. Чтобы они не удалялись - не удаляйте их.

Comment: Отлично, спасибо за ответ, но я ожидал ответ иначе... Дело в том, что неделю назад я смотрел иностранного кодера. Я попытался следовать его  стилю работы с GIT'ом. (он работал именно так), но позже потерял ссылку

Comment: возможно, на видео при склейке потерялось пару команд или комментарий.

Comment: @KoVadim вовсе нет, он все делал транслируюя (год назад)

Comment: Ну тогда показывайте видео. А пока я двумя руками поддерживаю первый комментарий.

Comment: @AlexeyTen хмм.. Странный вы однако человек.. Ссылку я потерял, может быть поэтому я и обратился, чтобы мне помогли?

Comment: @NappySays непонятно чего вы ожидаете. Объясните, в чем заключается стиль работы того кодера, если нет ссылки. Вы просите помощи, но не ясно, что ожидаете. Конкретно на вопрос "что вы делаете не так" - вам ответили. Команда `git merge` сливает все изменения. Если вы удаляли там файлы, то после слияния они будут удалены.

Comment: вот так сокращённо выглядит ваш вопрос для стороннего наблюдателя: 1. я удаляю файлы. 2. файлы удалились. 3. что я делаю не так? // единственный возможный разумный ответ уже изложен в первом комментарии.

Comment: шикарный вопрос, и отвратительные ответы. Мне бы тоже хотелось знать, как быть в такой ситуации. Но ответа нет.